UI List: when add item and then rename, it did not update stored property
Used this (material_uilist.py Create an interface which is similar to the material list box) example with materials list. When you rename material(item) in the uilist or in blender UI it update name visually in uilist. But if you call stored names it show an old name:
import bpy
names = [i.name for i in bpy.context.scene.custom]
print(names)

How to update stored names in this case?

Can you share a bit more code of the actual setup you have? We can't really help you debug much if you don't show us at least the main parts of what you're working with.

https://gist.github.com/p2or/30b8b30c89871b8ae5c97803107fd494
exactly this code. It creates addon panel in Text Editor dev tab. Here you press "Add all available Materials" button and it adds all Materials in the list. Then you rename one material by double click for different. After this use my code above and you see that material name did not changed. Only visually in the list.

Depends on what you are trying to do. You can:

Subscribe to a material name change with bpy.msgbus.

Use bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post to synchronize the data.

Use a dynamic bpy.props.EnumProperty list, by using a function for items.

Use bpy.data.materials for bpy.types.UILayout.template_list directly.

Just collect names from the pointer properties [i.material.name for i in bpy.context.scene.custom].


The collection item that holds the PointerProperty does not know that the material's name has been change.

Thank you! [i.material.name for i in bpy.context.scene.custom] is what I looked for.
